# Execute ReactiveUI Command from Event in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, command, reactiveui

I have entry fields in a Xamarin Forms page that I want to trigger a ReactiveUI command when the user is finished entering text into them. I am using ReactiveUI.Events.XamForms and am trying to trigger a command based off of the Unfocused event, but I am not sure how to set up the command to get that to work.

Here is my XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rxui:ReactiveContentPage
  x:Class="XamarinReactiveUISwipeView.MainPage"
  x:TypeArguments="vm:MainPageViewModel"          
  xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:XamarinReactiveUITest.ViewModel;assembly=XamarinReactiveUITest"
  xmlns:rxui="clr-namespace:ReactiveUI.XamForms;assembly=ReactiveUI.XamForms"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
  xmlns:ios="clr- namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core" 
  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true">
    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Margin="10,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Text="Task ID: " />
            <Entry x:Name="EntryTaskID" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Margin="10,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Text="Task Name: " />
            <Entry x:Name="EntryTaskName" />
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</rxui:ReactiveContentPage>
```

Here is my code behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : ReactiveContentPage<MainPageViewModel>
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = new MainPageViewModel();

        this.WhenActivated(disposable =>
        {
            this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.TheTaskItem.TaskID, page => page.EntryTaskID.Text)
            .DisposeWith(disposable);
            this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.TheTaskItem.TaskName, page => page.EntryTaskName.Text)
            .DisposeWith(disposable);
            EntryTaskName.Events().Unfocused.InvokeCommand(ViewModel, vm => vm.TheCommand);
        });
    }        
}
```

here is my model:

```
public class TaskItem 
{
    public TaskItem() { }

    public string TaskID { get; set; }
    public string TaskName { get; set; }        
}
```

and here is my view model:

```
public class MainPageViewModel : ReactiveObject
{                

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        TheTaskItem = new TaskItem { TaskID = "1", TaskName = "TheTaskName" };

        TheCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create<FocusEventArgs, Unit>(ExecuteTheCommand);                        
    }        

    public ReactiveCommand<FocusEventArgs, Unit> TheCommand { get; }

    private void ExecuteTheCommand(FocusEventArgs args)
    {
        //do something
    }                              

    private TaskItem _theTaskItem;

    public TaskItem TheTaskItem
    {
        get => _theTaskItem;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _theTaskItem, value);
    }
    
}
```

In the view model above, it won't compile, but I can't figure out how to set up the ExecuteTheCommand method. The error is:

> 'void MainPageViewModel.ExecuteTheCommand(FocusEventArgs)' has the wrong return type

But in looking at examples, it looked like methods with void returns use the Unit type.

What do I need to do here to set up the command properly to get this to work?

Comment: The format of ReactiveCommand is `ReactiveCommand.Create<TInput, TOutput>`. `TOutput` is the return type. Given your declaration, `ExecuteTheCommand` must return a `Unit`. If this is not what you want, then perhaps you want `...Create<TInput>` In two places that you have `<FocusEventArgs, Unit>`, change to `<FocusEventArgs>`. This declaration implies that the return type is `void`.

Comment: OK, I had first tried changing <FocusEventArgs, Unit> to <FocusEventArgs> in both places, but when I changed public ReactiveCommand<FocusEventArgs, Unit> TheCommand { get; } to public ReactiveCommand<FocusEventArgs> TheCommand { get; }, the error turned to "The non-generic type 'ReactiveCommand' cannot be used with type arguments". But when I left that with both types and only changed the Create to have <FocusEventArgs>, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In comment above, OP says that this works if change:

```
TheCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create<FocusEventArgs, Unit>(ExecuteTheCommand);
```

to:

```
TheCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create<FocusEventArgs>(ExecuteTheCommand);
```

---

Unexpectedly, the type of the variable that holds the result of `Create`, **does not** use that same generic type signature. It needs to be:

```
public ReactiveCommand<FocusEventArgs, Unit> TheCommand { get; }
```

According to the doc in link by Rodney Littles in comment, `Unit` is used to represent "void return type". (Generic type "TOutput" would be "void"; but "void" is not a valid Generic type.)

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/commands/#creating-commands

Comment: @Rodney Littles: yes, I had read through that and many other examples, but it wasn't clear from that, to me, at least, that when calling another function like the ExecuteTheCommand function above, that it would only have the TInput, but that the TheCommand would have both TInput and TOutput. Before I had submitted this question,I had originally begun by removing the TOutput from the TheCommand definition and that was what right away gave me compiler errors and so I didn't expect to leave the TOutput there yet not in the other line.

Comment: I guess my point in linking the docs is to figure out why it's unclear?  There are some runtime issues you will get with typing using InvokeCommand, which are similar to this.  Unfortunately, you just have to pay close attention when you are defining the Create,to be sure you only provide generic types you intend to use.

Comment: @RodneyLittles - what caused VinceL to miss the correct solution, is the use of `Unit` to represent "void return type". I myself have never seen this before - is it unique to ReactiveUI?  It has the unexpected consequence that the generic typing `<FocusEventArgs>` needed on `Create` is different than the generic typing `<FocusEventArgs, Unit>` needed on the variable that holds the result of Create. Such a difference is highly unusual, and rather confusing, IMHO.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I don't believe it is unique to ReactiveUI.  Unit represents A return type where void is the lack of a return all together.  So in the Rx world we need everything to "signal completion", which is why we use Unit.

The return type is only needed on the `Create` when you are explicitly consuming it.  It's very much a "use what you need" model.  Generic commands are confusing, because we allow for a return type, which you don't get from `ICommand`

Comment: @RodneyLittles - OK. They needed a way to pass around a result, even when there is no value to return. Or in low-level technical terms, something that could be boxed into an `Object`, yet could be uniquely recognized as "there is no value". It also makes the Generic typing cleaner, to always have it be `<TInput, TOutput>`, even when there is no value to return.  Older .Net class libraries got complicated if you needed to handle more than one of `<TInput>`, `<TOutput>`,and `<TInput,TOutput>`. `Unit` unifies those into `<TInput,TOutput>` - that supports `<TInput, Unit>`, `<Unit, TOutput>`. Nice.